# Angular2 How to get specific data that users choose after selecting choices from dropdown option.

Tags: forms, angular, request

Hi I am really new to Angular2 (I know most of the concepts that angular2 provides tho) and I am having problems with getting specific data after choosing some options.

Currently, I have fake database and created some profiles of random people in the database.

And I have components with dropdown options. I want users to choose one of the options and once they are done with choosing, I want them to click 'Complete' button.

Once they do, they will be redirected to another component that shows data corresponding to their choice.

I am guessing I need to store data that users choose into a service and communication between these two components(one components with options, the other with lists of information based on users' choice) should utilize the service.

But I've got no idea how to do so. Help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed.

Comment: I haven't really done anything except creating data in inmemorydatabase :( Don't know where to start

Comment: https://angular.io/ is a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,Define you routes with an parameter like '/anotherRouter:option'

Then, keep the selected option in you component.

```
<select id="option" name="option" required [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" #address="ngModel">
    ...
</select>
```

Then, By click the Complete button, goto another component like this.

```
<button (click)="go()">Complete</button>
```

And at your component, define a function go like this(let guess you have inject Router from @angular/router):

```
go() {
    this.router.navigate(['anotherRouter', selectedOption]);
}
```

Then get the selectedOption in your new component from the Params of `@angular/router` like `+params['option']`(the parameter passed while navigate).